# Blur filter inside parent with overflow:hidden + border radius+transform on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I want to blur a div inside a parent, but Firefox won't let me.

I've made a minimum working example which work on Chrome and Safari, but doesn't on Firefox.

It looks like it is the combination of `border-radius`, `overflow: hidden` and `transform` that creates the issue.

Disabling any of these, and the blur works like a charm. Is this a bug ? Is there something I can do ? a workaround ?

```css
.parent {
  /* attributes only for showing purpose*/
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  /* attributes actually important in this MWE*/
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  /* attributes only for showing purpose*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* attributes actually important in this MWE*/
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  transform: translateY(5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <p>If you can read this, blur does not work</p> 
    <p>If you can read this, blur does not work</p> 
    <p>If you can read this, blur does not work</p> 
    <div class="child">
      If the only readable text you see is this, blur works 
    <div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I was using a transform to make a transition on hover. My workaround (that I'm not satisfied with) as of today is to use a bottom position and change only this one. This is not a good workaround for me as it forces me to set a bottom position that is not accurate. But for this element in particulary, it works because it is ouside the parent in one of the states (thus hidden), so the position can be a little off.